# Simplexmlconverter, ElementList with Element and Attribute

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, retrofit

I'm trying to parse an XML with retrofit but I'm stuck in an ElementList.

My XML looks like this:

```
<OBJECT>
    <LIST>
       <ITEM attribute="20160119">tue</ITEM>
       <ITEM attribute="20160118">wed</ITEM>
       <ITEM attribute="20160117">thu</ITEM>
    </LIST>
    <OTHER>some text</OTHER>
</OBJECT>
```

My models looks like this:

```
@Root (name = "OBJECT", strict = false)
class Object {

    @Element (name = "OTHER", required = false)
    String other;
    @Element (name = "LIST", required = false)
    List list;

    //Constructor and getters

}

@Root (name = "LIST", strict = false)
class LIST {

    @ElementList (name = "ITEM", inline = true, required = false)
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    //Constructor and getters

}

@Root (name = "ITEM", strict = false)
class Item {

    @Attribute (name = "attribute", required = false)
    String attribute;
    @Element (required = false)
    String value;

    //Constructor and getters

}
```

The *Item* objects in the list have the correct *attribute* but the *value* is null.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve changing

**@Element** (required = false)
String value;

to

**@Text** (required = false)
String value;

hope this could be useful to somebody.